# A question on existence of a set

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $X\subset\mathbb R$ and let $f,g:X→X$ be continuous functions such that $f(X)∩g(X)=\varnothing$ and $f(X)\cup g(X)=X$. Which one of the following sets cannot be equal to $X$?

1. $[0,1]$
2. $(0,1)$
3. $[0,1)$
4. $\mathbb R$

   *What I tried*: $f(X)∩g(X)=\varnothing$ implies $f(X)^c\cup g(X)^c=X$ and I already have $f(X)\cup g(X)=X$. Now I am stuck. Kindly help.

Comment: \emptyset gives $\emptyset$, better than \phi.

Comment: ok..thanks user4894

Comment: And \varnothing gives $\varnothing$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are probably useful:

1. The continuous image of a compact set under a continuous map is compact.
2. Same for a connected set.
3. The compact connected sets inside of $R$ are exactly the closed intervals.

Can you write $R$ as a disjoint union of 2 closed intervals?

Comment: @AreaMan..thanks..I know these facts and option 1 is conclusive from these but I wanted to prove it by implications.

Comment: @mathlover I don't understand what you mean... what kind of implications?